# Translating SQL with self JOIN into SPARQL

Tags: sql, sparql

I'm trying to convert a SQL query into SPARQL, and i'm getting close, but I can't quite seem how to get past the self JOIN that the SQL query does.

Here's the SQL (Q: calculate stackoverflow user's accepted answer percentage):

```
SELECT 
    ( Count(a.Id) / (SELECT Count(*) FROM posts WHERE OwnerUserId = 45 AND PostTypeId = 2) * 100) AS AcceptedPercentage
FROM
    posts q
  INNER JOIN
    posts a ON q.AcceptedAnswerId = a.Id
WHERE
    a.OwnerUserId = 45
  AND
    a.PostTypeId = 2;
```

Here's what I've got so far in SPARQL:

```
SELECT
    (count(?answers) AS ?totalAnswers) 
    (count(?acceptedAnswers) AS ?totalAcceptedAnswers)
    ((count(?acceptedAnswers)/count(?answers))*100 AS ?acceptedPercentage)
WHERE {
    {
        #all answers
        ?answers a vocab:posts .

        #user 45
        ?answers vocab:posts_OwnerUserId 45 .

        #accepted answers
        ?answers vocab:posts_PostTypeId 2 .

        #set the answers id variable
        ?answers vocab:posts_Id ?answerId .

    } UNION {

        #all answers
        ?acceptedAnswers a vocab:posts .

        #user 45
        ?acceptedAnswers vocab:posts_OwnerUserId 45 .

        #is type answer
        ?acceptedAnswers vocab:posts_PostTypeId 2 .

        #accepted answer ID matches the overal ID of the question
        ?acceptedAnswers vocab:posts_AcceptedAnswerId ?acceptedAnswerId
        FILTER( ?answerId = ?acceptedAnswerId )

    }
}
```

Here's the data contained in a typical post (where vocab:posts_PostTypeId=2 means "answer"):

```
vocab:posts_AcceptedAnswerId    104 -
vocab:posts_AnswerCount         11  -
vocab:posts_Body                "here's the body of the question"   -
vocab:posts_CommentCount        0   -
vocab:posts_CreationDate        "2009-04-30T07:48:06"^^xsd:dateTime -
vocab:posts_FavoriteCount       11  -
vocab:posts_Id                  3   -
vocab:posts_LastActivityDate    "2009-06-05T04:01:09"^^xsd:dateTime -
vocab:posts_LastEditDate        "2009-04-30T08:05:02"^^xsd:dateTime -
vocab:posts_LastEditorUserId    22  -
vocab:posts_OwnerUserId         22  -
vocab:posts_PostTypeId          1   -
vocab:posts_Score               21  -
vocab:posts_Tags                "<unix><package-management><server-management>" -
vocab:posts_Title               "Best practices for keeping UNIX packages up to date?"  -
vocab:posts_ViewCount           548 -
rdf:type                        vocab:posts -
rdfs:label                      "posts #3"
```

How would this be performed in SPARQL?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Some data

It's easier if we have some sample data to work with.  Based on the properties that you're using (though I changed the names a little bit for readability), here's some sample data that describes ten answers, six of which are accepted:

```
@prefix : <http://stackoverflow.com/q/28101179/1281433/> .

:answer0 a :Post ; :hasId 0 ; :hasOwnerUserId 45 ; :hasPostTypeId 2 . :question0 a :Post ; :hasAcceptedAnswer 0.
:answer1 a :Post ; :hasId 1 ; :hasOwnerUserId 45 ; :hasPostTypeId 2 . :question1 a :Post ; :hasAcceptedAnswer 1.
:answer2 a :Post ; :hasId 2 ; :hasOwnerUserId 45 ; :hasPostTypeId 2 . :question2 a :Post ; :hasAcceptedAnswer 2.
:answer3 a :Post ; :hasId 3 ; :hasOwnerUserId 45 ; :hasPostTypeId 2 . :question3 a :Post ; :hasAcceptedAnswer 3.
:answer4 a :Post ; :hasId 4 ; :hasOwnerUserId 45 ; :hasPostTypeId 2 . :question4 a :Post ; :hasAcceptedAnswer 4.
:answer5 a :Post ; :hasId 5 ; :hasOwnerUserId 45 ; :hasPostTypeId 2 . :question5 a :Post ; :hasAcceptedAnswer 5.
:answer6 a :Post ; :hasId 6 ; :hasOwnerUserId 45 ; :hasPostTypeId 2 . :question6 a :Post ; :hasAcceptedAnswer 96.
:answer7 a :Post ; :hasId 7 ; :hasOwnerUserId 45 ; :hasPostTypeId 2 . :question7 a :Post ; :hasAcceptedAnswer 97.
:answer8 a :Post ; :hasId 8 ; :hasOwnerUserId 45 ; :hasPostTypeId 2 . :question8 a :Post ; :hasAcceptedAnswer 98.
:answer9 a :Post ; :hasId 9 ; :hasOwnerUserId 45 ; :hasPostTypeId 2 . :question9 a :Post ; :hasAcceptedAnswer 99.
```

That's a little bit condensed, but each row has data like this, one question and one answer:

```
:answer9  a              :Post ;
        :hasId           9 ;
        :hasOwnerUserId  45 ;
        :hasPostTypeId   2 .

:question9  a               :Post ;
        :hasAcceptedAnswer  99 .
```

### Some SPARQL

Now we can use a query like this to get the results we're looking for:

```sql
prefix : <http://stackoverflow.com/q/28101179/1281433/>

select (count(?answer) as ?nanswers) 
       (count(?question) as ?naccepted)
       (100*?naccepted/?nanswers as ?percentAccepted)
where { 
  ?answer a :Post ;
          :hasId ?id ;
          :hasOwnerUserId 45 ;
          :hasPostTypeId 2 .
  optional { 
    ?question a :Post ;
              :hasAcceptedAnswer ?id .
  }
}
```

```
------------------------------------------
| nanswers | naccepted | percentAccepted |
==========================================
| 10       | 6         | 60.0            |
------------------------------------------
```

### About the SQL

It's worth noting that in the SPARQL query, I used optional so that I was ending up with "rows" like:

```
-------------------------
| answer   | question   |
=========================
| :answer0 | :question0 |
| :answer1 | :question1 |
| :answer2 | :question2 |
| :answer3 | :question3 |
| :answer4 | :question4 |
| :answer5 | :question5 |
| :answer6 |            |
| :answer7 |            |
| :answer8 |            |
| :answer9 |            |
-------------------------
```

That's actually something you can do in the SQL version, too, just not with **inner join**.  I've found [Jeff Atwood's *A Visual Explanation of SQL Joins*](http://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/) useful here.   You'd actually be looking for a **left outer join**:

[image: left join screenshot from atwood article]

For instance, [this query on the Stack Exchange Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/267169/percent-of-answers-accepted?UserId=1281433) computes the percentage of my answers that have been accepted (but the UserId is a parameter, so you can change it easily):

```sql
select count(a.id) as nAnswers,
       count(q.id) as nAccepted,
       100.0*count(q.id)/count(a.id) as rate
from Posts a
left outer join Posts q
     on q.AcceptedAnswerId = a.id
where a.OwnerUserId = ##UserId##
      and a.PostTypeId = 2
```

In light of that, we can make a bit more of a line by line comparison.  The optional takes care of the **left outer join**, and it's implicit which variables it's based on;  it's whatever variables they have in common.  In this case, that's just **?id**.

```
select (count(?answer) as ?nanswers)
       (count(?question) as ?naccepted)
       (100*?naccepted/?nanswers as ?percentAccepted)
where { 
  ?answer a :Post ;                     #-- from Posts a
          :hasId ?id ;                  
          :hasOwnerUserId 45 ;          #-- where a.OwnerUserId = 45
          :hasPostTypeId 2 .            #--       and a.PostTypeId = 2
  optional {                            #-- left outer join on a.id 
    ?question a :Post ;                 #-- from Posts q
              :hasAcceptedAnswer ?id .  
  }
}
```

It actually would be possible to translate the original SQL query that made use of a subquery as well, though.  It would look more like this:

```sql
prefix : <http://stackoverflow.com/q/28101179/1281433/>

select ?nAnswers ?nAccepted (100*?nAccepted/?nAnswers as ?percentAccepted)
where { 
  { 
    select (count(?answer) as ?nAnswers) where {
      ?answer a :Post ;
             :hasId ?id ;
             :hasOwnerUserId 45 ;
             :hasPostTypeId 2 .
    }
  }
  {
    select (count(?answer) as ?nAccepted) where {
      ?answer a :Post ;
              :hasId ?id ;
              :hasOwnerUserId 45 ;
              :hasPostTypeId 2 .
      ?question a :Post ;
               :hasAcceptedAnswer ?id .
    }
  }
}
```

```
------------------------------------------
| nAnswers | nAccepted | percentAccepted |
==========================================
| 10       | 6         | 60.0            |
------------------------------------------
```

Comment: the data that this is running on is over the actual data dump for the server fault stack exchange site, so you can run that SQL query on the SO data explorer... (which you appear to have done already)

Comment: OK thank you. Currently i'm trying to run it and play with it a little bit. i'll let you know if anything is behaving weirdly